# Magento 2: How to check If Magento Core files got corrupted

Tags: magento2, frontend, frontend-error, magento-core

I am working with `Magento 2,` Installed with Sample Data given in `Luma theme`. I have tried to `Delete all products` from `Magento backend`, It Did not complete the process. Then I tied to `Delete using SQl`.

After deleting my `Magento Front-end` is not loading properly.

I have tried `CLI` commands many time, but it still looks the same.

Now I want to check if `Magento core` files got `corrupted`, **if so How can I find and fix the issues.**

[image]

> **Here is the Screen shot of the Console.**

[image]

> **below is the error in Console.**

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):26 GET https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):25 GET https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/requirejs/require.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/requirejs/require.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):280 GET https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
(index):26 GET https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/mage/requirejs/mixins.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
requirejs-config.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:48
    at requirejs-config.js:49
    at requirejs-config.js:688
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:48
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:49
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:688
(index):181 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):181
(anonymous) @ (index):181
(index):552 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):552
(anonymous) @ (index):552
(index):646 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):646
(anonymous) @ (index):646
mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:13 Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Ensure you are using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the snippet we provide.
T @ mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:121
(anonymous) @ mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:122
(anonymous) @ mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:122
(anonymous) @ mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:123
3(index):313 GET https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2 404 (Not Found)
2(index):551 GET https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2 404 (Not Found)
10(index):1 GET https://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE/pub/static/version1528789013/frontend/Magento/luma/fr_BE/fonts/opensans/bold/opensans-700.woff 404 (Not Found)
```

> php bin/magento setup:static-contents:deploy

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Failed loading c:\xampp\php\ext\xdebug.dll
Requested languages: en_US
Requested areas: frontend, adminhtml
Requested themes: Magento/blank, Magento/luma, Magento/backend
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> en_US ===
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2120 files; errors: 0
---

=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> en_US ===
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2195 files; errors: 0
---

=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US ===
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2058 files; errors: 0
---

=== Minify templates ===

Successful: 894 files modified
---

New version of deployed files: 1528788675
```

Comment: Check magento logs and browser console logs

Comment: I have updated the question with Console. Please check if you can find.

Comment: Try to delete pub/static/frontend folder and run static content deploy command also remove cache from var/cache folder.

Comment: Yes, I have tied that 4 times till now. I have 4 version of frontend now.

Comment: you should try with fresh Magento version difficult say where the issue.

Comment: Yes, I can start because It is testing version, I wanted to trace where I did wrong, so i will be careful on live orProduction Version of Magento

Comment: Please share what you run for static content deploy?

Comment: Can I update ques with All things i will get when i run static -content:deploy